# CreateTableOne - Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : error code 1 from Lapack routine 'dgesdd'

Tags: r

I'm taking a course in causal inference, and we are using the data set Right heart catheterization from this site: https://biostat.app.vumc.org/wiki/Main/DataSets

My code is the following:

```
library(tableone)
library(Matching)

#creat a data set with just these variables, for simplicity
ARF <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='ARF')
CHF <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='CHF')
Cirr <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='Cirrhosis')
colcan <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='Colon Cancer')
Coma <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='Coma')
COPD <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='COPD')
lungcan <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='Lung Cancer')
MOSF <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='MOSF w/Malignancy')
sepsis <- as.numeric(data$cat1=='MOSF w/Sepsis')
female <- as.numeric(data$sex=='Female')
died <- as.numeric(data$death=='Yes')
age <- data$age
treatment <- as.numeric(data$swang1=='RHC')
meanbp1 <- data$meanbp1

#new data set
mydata <- cbind(ARF,CHF,Cirr,colcan,Coma,lungcan,MOSF,sepsis,
                age,female,meanbp1,treatment,died)
mydata <- data.frame(mydata)

#covariates we will use (shorter list than you would use in practice)
xvars <- c("ARF","CHF","Cirr","colcan","Coma","lungcan","MOSF","sepsis",
           "age","female","meanbp1")

#look at table 1
table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = xvars,strata = "treatment",
                         data = mydata,test = FALSE)
##include standardized mean difference (SMD)
print(table1,smd=TRUE)
```

But when I try to run this script, I have the following problem:

```
> table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = xvars,strata = "treatment",
+                          data = mydata,test = FALSE)
Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : error code 1 from Lapack routine 'dgesdd'
```

And I don't know how to fix this problem. Does anyone knows?

Comment: Your code runs fine for me with the `rhc` dataset. I can't replicate the error you're getting. That error occurs when you try `solve` matrices with exactly the same values so I'm not sure where that would be coming from in your code.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have `test = TRUE` or somehow duplicate vectors so they're all the same? My only other thought would be to update R and `tableone` as going through the github there's some notes about that error.